# Big animation iPhone with CCSpriteFrameCache - plist

Tags: iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I have a problem when try to load the big animation with about 54 images (320x480 each image) into CCSpriteFrameCache, I can't use plist for this. How can I make the animation work? At this time, my animation can't work on iPhone 2G, 3G, and iPod.

Thank for your help,
John

Answer (score 0):

You won´t be able to do it...
Consider playing a video or just animating an small portion of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to determine why the animation has 54 images that are all the width/height of the screen.  This is an unnecessary number of images.

Break the animation down:

```
Is the background 'static' (does it move around, change constantly, etc?)
```

If it moves around a bit, but is really part of a much larger "canvas" then simply export out the entire background canvas and perform the movements yourself using the Cocos2D Actions available to you (CCMoveTo, CCJumpTo, CCDelayTime, CCSequence, etc)

```
What in the animation moves around, and how does it move around? 
Can it be broken into much smaller bits and the frames for the various "characters"
or "movable objects" within the scene be exported out onto a sprite sheet (saved out
via Zwoptex?)
```

A good animation sequence should be a series of much smaller images, all working together in unison to create the final "animation sequence".

If you break it down, I wouldn't be surprised if you were able to reduce your 54 images at 320x480 each down to a handful of 512x512 spritesheets (ala Zwoptex).

If your having trouble breaking it down, I would be available to look at the final animation and help you determine what could be minimized to reduce the overhead.